# Joomla DB Query with join over three tables

Tags: mysql, join, joomla

in my Joomla 2.5 Template I´ve using following JOIN query to get some infos out of two  tables (#_*content and #*_attachments)

```
    ->select(array('a.description','a.display_name','a.parent_id','a.filename','a.url', 'b.title', 'b.id','b.state','c.title'))
    ->from('#__attachments AS a')
    ->join('INNER', '#__content AS b ON (a.parent_id = b.id)')
    ->where("b.state = 1")
    ->order("RAND()");
```

How can I add one more join for table #_*categories to get also the categories title (here namend as 'c.title'.)?  The Id of the categories row is saved as catid in #*_content. I expect the assignment should look something like:

```
->join('INNER', '#__content AS b ON (c.id = b.catid)')
```

Thanks,

tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

`->join('INNER', '#__categories AS c ON b.catid = c.id')`

Please consider adding an LEFT JOIN for `attachments` IF it's possible that an item in `content` has no attachment and using as the main table `content`

Comment: Hi Valentin or everybody, before I start a new thread, maybe you read this. I´m not sure if this is possible anyway with one query. but do you see a way to get also the title of the parent category. pseudo: get parent.title where c.parent_id = parent.id?